# Is There a way to save files in the iPhone flash memory with phonegap?

Tags: iphone, cordova, web-applications

my question is quite simple: When i save files with phonegap API, those file are saved in the HTML 5 storage DB ( wrapped in Phonegap ) or in the iPhone memory?

If you have understood, i prefer the second option, because there isn't the limit of 5 MB....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), which does have a 5MB limit. But keep in mind that Local Storage is more for key/value pairs. While 5MB is not a lot for, say, multimedia files, it's a fair amount for just data.

If what you're after is the saving of files to the device, check out PhoneGap's documentation on the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File). This allows files to be saved to each device's respective directories.

I'm not sure about storage limits, but these would be dictated by the devices themselves (and not by PhoneGap).

Comment: So, for example is it possible to make an html page that have the only task of download all the things that i must use ( updates, photos and so on... ) ?

Comment: It's possible, but not recommended. If these are core files that are part of your app, it's better to include them in the *www* folder and include them with your app. If you use downloaded files to alter the look or behavior of your application, Apple may view that as you circumventing their review process for updates... and potentially deny you approval. If you're building an RSS reader, then sure - downloading assets and content makes sense. But if your goal is to host your app's files yourself, allowing you to change them at your convenience - that may be a bit more problematic.

Comment: However my problem is not to update the entire app ( the graphics remain the same ), but only the data that i use. For example i must build an app that shows a few city travels, and i want to update them. So can i make a folder named "data" where i store all media files ( outside the "www" folder )?

Comment: If it's supplemental data to your app... then yes, I think the File API is what you're after. I've not used it myself, but would recommend checking out the documentation to see how each device handles storing/retrieving files... as the locations are a bit different, depending on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Phonegap saves files to a server (which seems weird), it obviously have to save it to iPhone memory, whether using a database or not.

What's that 5 MB limit you speak of?

Comment: iOS has a 5 MB limit on HTML5 databases.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap provides a number of objects that give you access to the file system, whether it's on iOS, Android, or Blackberry. Check the [docs for File](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File) for more information and examples.